# How can I set focus on an html control in electron framework?

Tags: html, typescript, electron

I am trying to set focus on a control in Electron when the **initial BrowserWindow loads.**

I know there are alternative ways to do this through jQuery, JavaScript, etc, but is there something specific provided by the Electron framework?

I tried to focus the control using jQuery/JavaScript, but they do not seem to work in Electron.

Here is my code to set up Electron in the entry JS file app.js :-

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
nativeImage.createFromPath(path.join(__dirname,"demo.png"))
app.on('ready', () => {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 650,
        height: 120,
        transparent:true,
        frame: false,
    });
    window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/Wepage.html`);
});
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#googleFrame').focus();
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 300px;
            height:100px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            /* overflow-y: hidden; */
        }

        iframe {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
            background: transparent;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        }

        iframe {
            top: 450px;
            border: 20px solid black;
            opacity: 0.1;
        }

        .draggable-area {
            -webkit-app-region: drag;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="draggable-area">
    <center class="draggable-area">
      <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"
                    src="https://www.google.com"
                    width="600" height="60"
                    id="googleFrame"></iframe>
    </center>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen? You're trying to focus an iframe, not any input element.

Comment: By "focusing html control", do you just mean focusing the webview/main pane? Or do you want to focus something in the page? Are you trying to focus the google search box? That should be focused once the page loads. If it's not getting focused, you might have to use a workaround I can provide once I get more info. Also, should your `iframe` really be a `webview`?

Answer (score 1):

**you can use autofocus**

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"
                    src="https://www.google.com"
                    width="600" height="60"
                    id="googleFrame" autofocus ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific about ElectronJs "views", it is just regular html, css and javascript.

Are you sure you code is executing at all? It is kinda strange to put it after closing body tag.

Did you try to put focus on something else, like make a button element and try to focus on it?

Comment: Yes, I know regarding that. What I am trying to emphasize was that is there a way to set focus while initializing BrowserWindow, or just after it, in the app.js itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this with dev tools open, load the app without dev tools automatically loading and the focus functionality works. i.e. comment out `win.openDevTools();` from main.js.

I had a comparable problem - an input element was not being focussed when the page loaded using either `autofocus` attribute or javascript `element.focus()` within my electron app. Similar issues are reported on electron GitHub: in particular [#2317](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2317), [#1773](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1773), [#5900](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5900).

I found the issue was only apparent when dev tools were automatically opened from main.js:
My relevant  main.js code was pretty vanilla:

```js
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    ...
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      devTools: true
    } 
  })
  win.openDevTools();
  win.loadFile('myPage.html');
  ...
  }
```

Comment out `win.openDevTools();` and the focus() features worked correctly.